# Javascript Image resizing is not working properly in IE11 but working in remaing versions(10,9,8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am using wicket framework (html +java) in my application where i need to resize an image when the componenet loads.This code is working fine in IE8,9,10.But it is failing sometimes in IE11.
Some times it is able to resize and but sometimes it is not able to do so.Actully it is not going into the javascript code whenver it fails.
Please help me in solving the issue.

```
<img  wicket:id="bigImage" onload="resize_imgs(140,140,112,112)" />
```

Here the above image compnenet is calling following  javascript code and will perfrom the image resizing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resize_imgs(maxht, maxwt, minht, minwt) {
        alert("first line");
         var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        var resize_img = function (img, newht, newwt) {
            img.height = newht;
            img.width = newwt;
            alert("in resize image function :newht" + newht + "newwt:" + newwt);
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            var img = imgs[i];
            if (img.height > maxht || img.width > maxwt) {
                var old_ratio = img.height / img.width;
                var min_ratio = minht / minwt;
                if (old_ratio === min_ratio) {
                    alert("ratios equal");
                    resize_img(img, minht, minwt);
                }
                else {
                    var newdim = [img.height, img.width];
                    newdim[0] = minht;
                    newdim[1] = newdim[0] / old_ratio;
                    if (newdim[1] > maxwt) {
                        newdim[1] = minwt;
                        newdim[0] = newdim[1] * old_ratio;
                    }
                    alert("ratios not equal");
                    resize_img(img, newdim[0], newdim[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE1:**

In my appllication there are lot of images in a page and when we click on image or opens that page it will take first image or clicked image and will set it in top corner of the page.So whenever that component loads (img wicket:id="bigImage" onload="resize_imgs(140,140,112,112)" /> )we will call onload event.Now i have been trying with jquery.I updated it in the question.Could you please suggest me whether it is correct or not.

```
<img  class="resizeImage" wicket:id="bigImage" />   


$(document).ready(function(){   
$(".resizeImage").one("load", function() {  
// do stuff
var maxht=140;
var maxwt =140;
var minht=112;
var minwt=112;  
var img_height = $(this).height();
var img_width = $(this).width();

  if (img_height > maxht || img_width > maxwt) {
     var old_ratio = img_height / img_width;
     var min_ratio = minht / minwt;
  if (old_ratio === min_ratio) {
      $(this).css('height',minht);
      $(this).css('width',minwt); 
   } 
   else {
     var newdim = [img_height, img_width];
     newdim[0] = minht;  
     newdim[1] = newdim[0] / old_ratio;
  if (newdim[1] > maxwt) {
       newdim[1] = minwt;
       newdim[0] = newdim[1] * old_ratio;
     }
  $(this).css('height',newdim[0]);
  $(this).css('width',newdim[1]); 
     }
 }}).each(function() {
      if(this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
```

Comment: You call `resize_images` in the `onload`, but the function in the code is `resize_imgs`. Are they supposed to be the same, or do you have more code?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Yes, but that's not what I asked about. The code in `onload` calls the function `resize_images` that isn't included here, and there is no call shown to the function `resize_imgs`.

Comment: @Guffa Thank you so much for going through it.I have modified the code,here the onload function is 'resize_imgs(140,140,112,112)'  and i have updated wrongly.Now i corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image can be pulled from the cache immediately, then IE won't trigger the `load` event for the image at all.

You can check if the `complete` property of the image is `true`. Then the image is already loaded and you won't get a `load` event, so you can just call the function directly. Example:

```
var image = $('img');
if (image.prop('complete')) {
   resize_imgs(140,140,112,112);
} else {
   image.load(function(){
     resize_imgs(140,140,112,112);
   });
}
```

Comment: ,Where exactly we can keep the code you suggested in my code.Could you please tell me that if IE wont trigger load event for image ,then how it is able to do it in remaining versions.Should we remove onload event and keep some thing other?

Comment: @SiddhuS: You need to bind the event in the code instead of using the `onload` attribute in the element. Add code like the above to your script, adjusting the selector if needed, and looping through the images if you have more than one. You need to do that in the `load` or `ready` event for the document, so that the element exists first. I don't know if previous versions of IE works differently, that might also differ between different document modes, and IE might not be the only browser that supresses the event.

Comment: ,Thank you very much.Shall we implement the above change in jquery?Why because above code is in javascript and the one you are suggesting seems to in jquery.

Comment: @SiddhuS: You can use plain Javascript if you like, I wrote it in jQuery because the question is tagged with jQuery, and the code gets a bit simpler.

Comment: ,Actullay in my appllication there are lot of images in a page and when we click on image or opens that  page it will take first image or clicked image and will set it in top corner of the page.So whenever that component loads (img  wicket:id="bigImage" onload="resize_imgs(140,140,112,112)" /> )we will call onload event.Now i have been trying with jquery.I updated it in the question.Could you please have a look on it and suggest me whether it is correct or not.

Comment: @SiddhuS: Calling `.load()` on the elements won't trigger the event, you would need to use `.trigger('load')` for that.

Comment: ,It works after adding trigger.But it is able to resize whenever the document loads.But i have one more  requirement,that is whenever i click on the any one of the images then it should appear in the top left corener.It is appearing in top corener ,but it is not able to resize the copmonent which it was able to do when doucment loads.Could you please suggest?